# Aligning piecewise functions and function definition maths

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am unsure how to align the following so that `\mathbb{N}` is aligned with the `n` in `f(n)`. I have tried `\begin{align*}` but that just gave me a bunch of errors. Any help will be much appreciated!

```
It suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}\preceq \mathbb{N}$.
\\* Define $f : \mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ by \[
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
k &\text{if } n=2k \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z},\\
-k &\text{if } n=2k+1 \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}
\]
```

Comment: I'm not sure you really want a line break before “Define”, nor that you want “f(n)” aligned with the “ℕ”.

Answer (score 11):

The result is pretty horrible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
It suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}\preceq \mathbb{N}$.
\[
\begin{array}{@{} r @{} c @{} l @{} }
\text{Define }f \colon &\mathbb{N} & {} \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z} \text{ by}\\[1ex]
&f(n) &{}=\displaystyle
\begin{cases}
k &\text{if } n=2k \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z},\\
-k &\text{if } n=2k+1 \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, do a favor to your readers and do in the traditional way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
It suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}\preceq \mathbb{N}$.
Define $f \colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
\[
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
k &\text{if } n=2k \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z},\\
-k &\text{if } n=2k+1 \text{ for } k\in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd avoid the usage of *k*, speaking from a mathematical point of view:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
It suffices to show that $\mathbb{Z}\preceq \mathbb{N}$.
Define $f \colon\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ by
\[
f(n)=
\begin{cases}
\hphantom{-}\dfrac{n}{2} &\text{if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is even},\\[2ex]
-\dfrac{n-1}{2} &\text{if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is odd}.
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]